How do you check that one type extends another, using the typescript compiler API
I'm working on a tool (partly to see how it would work) to flatten a set of typescript definitions into a clean d.ts file (vs retaining all the helper types created to massage various shapes). Ignoring recursiveness this is working surprisingly well, with one irksome limitation.
I can't compare if one type literal extends another - something I'm certain should be trivial.
import ts from 'typescript';

const program = ts.createProgram([], {})
const checker = program.getTypeChecker();

// { result: any }
const node1 = ts.factory.createTypeLiteralNode([
  ts.factory.createPropertySignature([], "result", undefined, ts.factory.createKeywordTypeNode(ts.SyntaxKind.AnyKeyword))
]);


// { something: any }
const node2 = ts.factory.createTypeLiteralNode([
   ts.factory.createPropertySignature([], "something", undefined, ts.factory.createKeywordTypeNode(ts.SyntaxKind.AnyKeyword))
 ]);

checker.isTypeAssignableTo(
  checker.getTypeAtLocation(node1),
  checker.getTypeAtLocation(node2)
)

I've tried numerous variants of this - including omitting getTypeAtLocation. The call isTypeAssignableTo does work when checking things like false/true or string/number, but not literals.
I'm probably doing something very silly - either because it's obvious, or so heinously hard that it shouldn't be attempted at all.

Are you saying checker.isTypeAssignableTo does return true for your code, while it shouldn't?

Exactly, it returns true when it should return false

The TypeScript compiler is designed to do things in order from parse, to check, and then emit. When initializing the TypeChecker, it bind nodes in the program with symbols. It's not designed for someone to get a type checker, then create a node, and then use that with the type checker. It won't be reliable in this situation because the nodes don't have parents set and aren't bound with symbols from the program of that TypeChecker.
What you need to do is first get the source files parsed in the program (ensure no diagnostics via ts.getPreEmitDiagnostics(program)), then get the type checker. At that point you can get the nodes from a parsed source file that the type checker knows about via the program and call checker.isTypeAssignableTo(typeA, typeB) reliably.

This is unfortunate. Are there no plugins/tools built that convert typescript and need to know things about the types? The example I gave was a massive simplification - the actual usage does load the files from disk, but then mutates them (specifically by resolving TypeReferences, finding the relevant TypeLiteral and copying it in place of the reference).
I assume ts.factory.update* suffers the same problem?
All I really want is to get an answer to "what is the final shape of this thing" - after resolving all types

From my understanding, you'll need to emit, reparse the files, then use them in a new program or you'll need to come up with some other clever way of doing things (maybe some IR that you then compare instead), which depends on the situation. I opened an issue on the TS repo about type checking factory constructed files a few years ago: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43600
